# Using Linq-To-SQL, how can I ensure forced execution on a complex type?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

More LINQ questions from me, what a surprise.

So right now, I am working on a website that uses an internal SQLite data source. I'm using LINQ-To-SQL in order to "talk" to it, utilizing Entity Framework. Now, say I have a complex object. This object contains a List inside it, which in turn maps a One-To-Many relationship.

```
ParentObject {
    Integer Id
    List<RelatedObject> RelatedObjects
    string SomeField
}
RelatedObject {
    Integer Id
    ParentObject Parent
    NestedObject Nested
    string SomeField
}
NestedObject {
    Integer Id
    RelatedObject Parent
    string SomeField
}
```

Now this is a DB structure I cannot change. Suppose I am executing a query in a context on page load:

```
var results = context.ParentObjects.Where(parent => parent.SomeField == AnotherField).ToList();
```

As far as I know, using `ToList()` will "force" linq to execute the query there and then, causing us to not have to worry about deferred execution. So, it is safe to do this:

```
result = results.First();
```

(result is defined in the scope outside of results() due to an if() statement).

Now this works fine, until I try and execute an extension method, which does this:

```
// Assume this is an extension method on ParentObject
return this.RelatedObjects.Where(related => this.SomeField == related.SomeField).Select(related.Nested).First();
```

(very convoluted when I try and explain it)

We then get an exception because the DataContext from which "this" (The ParentObject) was created has been disposed.

My question is, how can I access the `List<RelatedObject> RelatedObjects` field inside `ParentObject` after the context has ended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm silly.

I forgot to disable Lazy-Loading in the context.

```
public Context()
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```